# breezejs Entity Framework angular

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, breeze

I am having issues getting the most recent version of the Breeze Angular client to query my Breeze service which is written with `VS2013`, `EF6`, and `WebAPI2`.

I have the service providing metadata and `json` to my endpoint(url); but, I seem to be having issues getting the `dataservice.js` file on the client setup correctly. Just injecting the service into the controller, fires off an undefined is not a function error.

My code is fairly close to the original example:

Am I missing something, it seems like Breeze is supposed to be simple to setup.
Is there a working sample somewhere for `EF6`, `BreezeAngular` that is `WebAPI2`; but, not `OData`?

Thank you in advance

```
//////////////////////
//  dataservice.js  //
//////////////////////

/* dataservice: data access and model management layer 
 * relies on Angular injector to provide:
 *     $timeout - Angular equivalent of 'setTimeout'
 *     breeze - the Breeze.Angular service (which is breeze itself)
 *     logger - the application's logging facility
 */


(function() {

angular.module('app').factory('dataservice', ['$http', '$q', '$timeout', 'breeze', 'logger', dataservice]);

function dataservice( $http, $q, $timeout, breeze, logger) {

    var serviceName = 'breeze/userPortal'; // route to the same origin Web Api controller

    // *** Cross origin service example  ***
    // When data server and application server are in different origins
    //var serviceName = 'http://sampleservice.breezejs.com/api/todos/';

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
    manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);

    //REVEALING MODULE
    var service = {
        addPropertyChangeHandler: addPropertyChangeHandler,
        createuser: createuser,
        deleteuser: deleteuser,
        getusers: getusers,
        hasChanges: hasChanges,
        purge: purge,
        reset: reset,
        removePropertyChangeHandler: removePropertyChangeHandler,
        saveChanges: saveChanges
    };

    return service;

    /*** implementation details ***/

    function addPropertyChangeHandler(handler) {
        // Actually adds any 'entityChanged' event handler
        // call handler when an entity property of any entity changes
        return manager.entityChanged.subscribe(function(changeArgs) {
            var action = changeArgs.entityAction;
            if (action === breeze.EntityAction.PropertyChange) {
                handler(changeArgs);
            }
        });
    }

    function createuser(initialValues) {
        return manager.createEntity('user', initialValues);
    }

    function deleteuser(user) {
        user && user.entityAspect.setDeleted();
    }

    function getusers() {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("users")
            .orderBy("LastName");
    }

    var promise = manager.executeQuery(query).catch(queryFailed);
    return promise;

    function queryFailed(error) {
        logger.error(error.message, "Query failed");
        return $q.reject(error); // so downstream promise users know it failed
    }
});

function hasChanges() {
    return manager.hasChanges();
}

function handleSaveValidationError(error) {
    var message = "Not saved due to validation error";
    try { // fish out the first error
        var firstErr = error.entityErrors[0];
        message += ": " + firstErr.errorMessage;
    } catch (e) { /* eat it for now */ }
    return message;
}

function removePropertyChangeHandler(handler) {
    // Actually removes any 'entityChanged' event handler
    return manager.entityChanged.unsubscribe(handler);
}

function saveChanges() {
    return manager.saveChanges()
        .then(saveSucceeded)
        .catch(saveFailed);

    function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
        logger.success("# of users saved = " + saveResult.entities.length);
        logger.log(saveResult);
    }

    function saveFailed(error) {
        var reason = error.message;
        var detail = error.detail;

        if (error.entityErrors) {
            reason = handleSaveValidationError(error);
        } else if (detail && detail.ExceptionType &&
            detail.ExceptionType.indexOf('OptimisticConcurrencyException') !== -1) {
            // Concurrency error 
            reason =
                "Another user, perhaps the server, " +
                "may have deleted one or all of the users." +
                " You may have to restart the app.";
        } else {
            reason = "Failed to save changes: " + reason +
                " You may have to restart the app.";
        }

        logger.error(error, reason);
        // DEMO ONLY: discard all pending changes
        // Let them see the error for a second before rejecting changes
        $timeout(function() {
            manager.rejectChanges();
        }, 1000);
        return $q.reject(error); // so downstream promise users know it failed
    }

}

//#region demo operations
function purge(callback) {
    return $http.post(serviceName + '/purge')
    .then(function () {
        logger.success("database purged.");
        manager.clear();
        if (callback) callback();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        logger.error("database purge failed: " + error);
        return $q.reject(error); // so downstream promise users know it failed
    });
}

function reset(callback) {
    return $http.post(serviceName + '/reset')
    .then(function () {
        logger.success("database reset.");
        manager.clear();
        if (callback) callback();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        logger.error("database reset failed: " + error);
        return $q.reject(error); // so downstream promise users know it failed
    });
}

//#endregion
```

Comment: looks to me like half of this function is in the wrong scope.  everything starting with `function hasChanges() {` is outside the scope of the `dataservice` function, was that intentional? note the placement of the closing function block `});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not structured properly.  You terminated the `dataservice` function early, immediately before `function hasChanges() {`.  this function, and all the functions declared after it, are no longer defined within `dataservice`.

Using the revealing module pattern, you attempt to assign `service.hasChanges` to the `hasChanges` function.  But the `hasChanges` function is not defined inside `dataservice`, it is defined outside `dataservice`, so the assignment returns `undefined`, thus the error `Undefined is not a function.`

move the closing block of your `dataservice` function `});` down to include all of it's functions.

Comment: Thank you , that did indeed fix the undefined error! I'm getting some new errors, which I will post if they are not duplicates.